# UITableViewCell with Custom View

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

i am desperately trying to add a custom View to a UITableViewCell. I have a UITableViewController in Storyboard wich is linked to a TestTableViewController Class and the prototype cell has the identifier "Cell2".

So this is the code in UITableViewController:

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return dataArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 190
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    let ticket = YellowTackleTicketComplete()
    ticket.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 335, height: 150)

    cell.addSubview(ticket)

    //        cell.textLabel!.text = tackl!.valueForKey("title") as? String
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    print(cell.subviews)


    return cell
}
```

The dataArray is just for testing purposes and has one item in it. So what i get is a Table View with one empty cell. In the Xcode UI Debugger i can see the custom view. But its not shown in the simulator or on a device.

[image]

If anyone can help, thank you so much!

This is the code of the view:

```
class YellowTackleTicketComplete: UIView {


    var containerView: UIView!
    var ticket: TacklTicket!
    var dropDownMenu: YellowDrawer!
    var dropDownBackground: YellowDrawerBackground!
    var ticketShadowLine: UIView!


    var lowAlphaView: UIView!
    var outbackButton: UIButton!
    var arrowView: UIView!

    var bounceHeight: CGFloat?
    var dropdownHeight: CGFloat?
    var topBorder: CGFloat?
    var bottomBorder: CGFloat?
    //let arrowLayer = CALayer()
    //let layerDelegate = LayerDelegate()
    var dropDownElements = [String]()
    var dropped = false
    var animating = false
    var delegate: YellowTackleTicketCompleteDelegate?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "highlighted", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        if keyPath == "frame" {
            // Set up DropdownMenu
            self.dropDownBackground.frame.size.height = self.dropDownMenu.frame.maxY
        }

    }

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if(!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0.0){
            let subviews = self.subviews.reverse()
            for member in subviews {
                let subPoint = member.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)
                if let result:UIView = member.hitTest(subPoint, withEvent:event) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func ticketTapped() {
                //if !animating {
        if !dropped {
            showDropdown()
            NSLog("#")
//            NSLog("Scrolling to \((dropDownMenu.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!)(the index of the tableview selection)")
//            dropDownMenu.scrollToRowAtIndexPath((dropDownMenu.indexPathForSelectedRow)!, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: false)
        } else {
            hideDropdown()
        }
        //        }
    }

    func showDropdown() {
        dropDownMenu.hidden = false
        self.ticket.drawShadowBeneathTicket()
        print("showing")
        if !animating {
            animating = true
            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                1.0,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                options: [],
                animations: {
                    self.dropDownMenu.frame.origin.y  = self.bottomBorder!

                }, completion: { _ in
                    //self.delegate?.menuOpen?()
                    self.animating = false
                    print(self.dropDownBackground.frame.size.height)
                    print(self.dropDownMenu.frame.maxY)
                }
            )
        }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.dropDownMenu!.setNeedsDisplay()
        dropped = true
    }

    func hideDropdown() {
        if !animating {
            animating = true
            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                0.7,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                options: [],
                animations: {
                    self.dropDownMenu.frame.origin.y  = self.topBorder! + self.bounceHeight!
                }, completion: nil
            )
        }
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            0.5,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone,
            animations: {
                self.dropDownMenu.frame.origin.y  = self.topBorder! - self.dropdownHeight!
            }, completion: { _ in
                //self.delegate?.menuClosed?()
                self.animating = false
                self.dropDownMenu.hidden = true
                self.ticket.setNeedsDisplay()
                self.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        )
        dropped = false
    }

    func initSubViews() {
        self.topBorder = self.frame.height*6/150
        self.bottomBorder = self.frame.height - self.topBorder!

        self.bounceHeight = 250
        self.dropdownHeight = 350

        containerView = UIView()
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topBorder!, width: self.bounds.width, height: dropdownHeight!+bounceHeight!)
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true

        ticket = TacklTicket()
        ticket.frame = self.bounds
        ticket.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YellowTackleTicketComplete.ticketTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        dropDownMenu = YellowDrawer()
        dropDownMenu.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: topBorder! - dropdownHeight!, width: containerView.bounds.width, height: dropdownHeight!)
        dropDownMenu.hidden = true
        dropDownMenu.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        dropDownMenu.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: .New, context: nil)

        dropDownBackground = YellowDrawerBackground()
        dropDownBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.bounds.width,self.dropDownMenu.frame.maxY)

        self.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(dropDownBackground)
        containerView.addSubview(dropDownMenu)
        self.addSubview(ticket)
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume YellowTackleTicketComplete() is a returning a UIView (or UILabel or something), but this code doesn't show what that view is or what it should be displaying.  Can you provide the code for the YellowTackleTicketComplete() struct/class?

Comment: You should be adding it to the cell's contentView, not the cell itself.

Comment: Thank you guys, but so far it didn't solve the problem :( I guess DJohnson is right. The Problem seems to be the YellowTackleTicketComplete View. (I tried a simply green UIView and it worked) I didn't consider this because the YellowTackleTicketComplete View works well if i put it in a simple ViewController's view. 
The YellowTackleTicketComplete view kind of complex. It's a card with a dropdown menu sliding out. Dynamically adapting the size of the cell will probably be the next problem :(  
I added the code for YellowTacklTicketComplete to the initial question. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a designated initializer for your `UIView` subview. That is either `init(frame:CGRect)` or in add it in Interface Builder. You are also not passing `let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]` to your cell, not sure if you're aware of that. You also never call `initSubViews()` which seems to be a big part of your custom view.

Comment: Shame on me. I definitely need the new facepalm emoticon. I think i have been working too long this week. I forgot to call initSubviews() :( Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
cell.addSubview(ticket)
```

try

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(ticket)
```

and the best place to customize cell's content is its init function.

Comment: Thanks a lot ale_stro. I tried this already and unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The custom view that i am trying to add seems to be the problem. It works fine on a normal view but not on a UITableViewCell's view :(

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you should try, set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false on the view you created programmatically since you are inserting it into an auto layout controller.

View that should also try just setting,
dropDownMenu, dropDownBackground, containerView and ticket
or

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath also try setting the property
`ticket.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Thanks for your help. beyowulf solved the "problem". It was my own fault. Forgot to call the custom initializer for the subviews :(